# Java GUI - Moving a circle with no "footprints"

Tags: java, events, user-interface

When I run the program and move the circle, it appears as if I'm drawing with a paintbrush in paint. I'm not quite sure what I did to make it to this, or what I can do to make it stop. All help is highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class MovingCar extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0;

    public MovingCar()
    {
        tm.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int c = e.getKeyCode();

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)      {
            velX = -1;
            velY = 0;
        }

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            velX = 1;
            velY = 0;
        }


    }   
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        if (x < 0)
        {
            velX = 0;
            x = 0;
        }

        if (x > 600)
        {
            velX = 0;
            x = 0;
        }


        repaint();  
        velY = 0;
        velX = 0;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MovingCar o = new MovingCar();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Circle Move");
        jf.setSize(600,400);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(o);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: Just as a side note while dig around the code, you should avoid `KeyListeners`, Key bindings are safer

Comment: At first, they seem more convaluted, but they are definatly more functional and easier to use.  Check [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: `KeyListener` is a low level interface, while it's useful, it's limited in the fact that the component it is registered to must be focusable and have focus.  Key bindings don't suffer from these restrictions, you can actually have 3 levels of focus control to make it more flexible.  Because key bindings use the `Action` API, the actions then become resuable. For example, you could put buttons onto your component that control the movement as well as key bindings at they could share the same instance of the action, reducing the complexity and increasing code resue :D

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `super.paintComponents(g);` instead of `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: +1, good eyes. You should only ever invoke super of the method that you are overriding. The fact that paintComponents() happens to exist is just lucky. But to answer your question it paints any components that might have been added to the panel.

Comment: @sonic `paintComponents` will paint any child components that the container has, `paintComponent` will paint the background of the actual component.  `paintComponent` is the lowest level of paint, where as `paintComponents` sits above it.  Have a look at [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more details